# Invertible Proof with transposed matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let A, B, C be square matrices that are invertible. Say I want to express X with no inverses

Say 
$$
(A^{T}A)^{-1}(X +B^ {T})(C^{-1}B^{-1})^{T} = I.
$$

I know that $A^{T}A$ = $I$, but where can I go from there?

Comment: The condition $\;A^tA=I\;$ is a very strong one. Do you know anything else about the other matrices?

Comment: I proved that myself. A square matrix transposed multipled by itself will create an identity matrix.

Comment: @user163737 Attention this is only true if the matrix is unitary.

Comment: @user163737, that is false. Read Surb's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Use [$(M^T)^{-1} = (M^{-1})^T$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Properties), $(M_1M_2)^T = M_2^TM_1^T$, [$(M_1M_2)^{-1}= M_2^{-1}M_1^{-1}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Other_properties) to see that $$(C^{-1}B^{-1})^{T}= ((BC)^{-1})^T = ((BC)^T)^{-1} = (C^TB^T)^{-1}. \quad (*)$$
Now note that
$$(A^{T}A)^{-1}(X +B^ {T})(C^{-1}B^{-1})^{T} = I \overset{(1)}{\iff} (X +B^ {T})(C^{-1}B^{-1})^{T} = A^TA \\ \overset{(*)}{\iff} (X+B^{T})(C^{T}B^{T})^{-1} = A^TA \overset{(2)}{\iff} X+B^{T}=A^TAC^{T}B^{T} \overset{(3)}{\iff} X =(A^TAC^{T}-I)B^{T}.$$

(1) Multiply on the left by $A^TA$

(2) Multiply on the right by $C^{T}B^{T}$

(3) Subtract $B^T$ and factorize

In particular if $A^TA=I,$ then $X = (C^T-I)B^T$.

Comment: What happened to $A^{T}A$ = $I$? How did you make it equal 1 on the left side?

Comment: @user163737 Do my edit answers your question?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks!

Comment: This works only if $\;A\;$ is unitary, which isn't given and, apparently, is based on something wrong the OP thinks he proved.

Comment: @Timbuc I improved my answer for the more general case.

Answer (score 1):

Note that from $(B^{-1})^T = (B^T)^{-1}$ and $(C^{-1})^T = (C^T)^{-1}$ one have
\begin{eqnarray}
(A^TA)^{-1}(X+B^T)(C^{-1}B^{-1})^T 
&=&
(X+B^T)(C^{-1}B^{-1})^T
\\&=& 
X(C^{-1}B^{-1})^T+B^T(C^{-1}B^{-1})^T 
\\&=& 
X (B^{-1})^T(C^{-1})^T+B^T(B^{-1})^T(C^{-1})^T 
\\&=& 
X (B^{-1})^T(C^{-1})^T+B^T(B^T)^{-1}(C^{-1})^T 
\\&=& 
X (B^{T})^{-1}(C^{T})^{-1}+(C^{T})^{-1} 
\end{eqnarray}
Now from $X X (B^{T})^{-1}(C^{T})^{-1}+(C^{T})^{-1}  =I$, you have that
$$
X (B^{-1})^T+I = C^T
$$
and
$$
X = (C^T-I) B^T.
$$